# How to create a Evernote note with tomorrow date title and specific tag with autohotkey script?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, evernote

I'm beginner of autohotkey script. I want to automatically create a note with tomorrow date and tagged with a specific tag.

Just like, simply press "ctrl+alt+n" and then open evernote and titled with `20190703(Wed) Todo` and tagged with `TODO` and categorized to a notebook named `MyWorkLog` and switch cursor to the content.

I've tried to create the note with date, day and also able to switch cursor to content. Thankfully it works.
I can press ctrl+alt+n, and then open evernote, tilted with `20190703(Wed) TODO` and switch cursor to content.
But what I don't know how to do is "tagged with `TODO` tag" and "categorized to `MyWorkLog` notebook".

Sorry for the ugly and dirty codes

```
^!N::
    Run Evernote
    Sleep 1000
    WinActivate
    Send, ^n
    Sleep 500

    day := A_WDAY
    day += 1
    if (day = 1){
        Day := "Sun"
    }
    if (day = 2){
        Day := "Mon"
    }
    if (day = 3){
        Day := "Tue"
    }
    if (day = 4){
        Day := "Wed"
    }
    if (day = 5){
        Day := "Thu"
    }
    if (day = 6){
        Day := "Fri"
    }
    if (day = 7){
        Day := "Sat"
    }

    date := %A_DD%
    nowDate := date
    nowDate += 1, days
    FormatTime, tomorrow, %nowDate%, dd

    Send, %A_YYYY%%A_MM%%tomorrow%(%Day%) TODO{Enter}{Tab}
    Sleep 500

    Return
```

It's ok for me if there are ways can finish this problem with java or python code.
Any ideas is appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention it: I am going to replace the "day" to "chinese day" like "一二三四五六日". So I need to implement the string of day.

Comment: Have you done a search to find what keyboard shortcuts Evernote uses to get the add tag dialog or move to notebook?  https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/209004807-Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Evernote-for-Windows Once you have those, it should be easy.

Comment: @PGilm Oh, thanks. I didn't survey that. I find the "F3" shortcut to get focus on tag field. I can set tag now, but still some problems of switching notebook.
When press shift+alt+n to search notebook, then send mynotebook name, it will type the name into the search field, but evernote won't react to the words for searching, even I press enter after a 1 second delay.

Comment: try the different "Send" types https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm. Or try it using paste (ctrl+v).